# Root path not rendering properly

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nestjs, angular-universal

I'm having an Angular application with Angular Universal to support Server-Side Rendering (SSR). I have a problem on a root page. All other routes works perfectly on a SSR, but the **"/"** does not. **As a try for a home route changed "/" to "/app" and it works correctly!!**. I'm using `NestJS` and `Firebase` Cloud Functions are executed to render it. The files Below are what i think might cause the problem.

**main.nest.ts**

```js
    // These are important and needed before anything else.
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
    import 'reflect-metadata';
    
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import { AppNestModule } from './app.nest.module';
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { Express } from 'express';
    import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
    import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
    
    enableProdMode(); // Faster server renders in production mode (development doesn't need it).
    
    admin.initializeApp(); // Initialize Firebase SDK.
    
    const server: Express = express(); // Create Express instance.
    
    // Handle HTTP POST request and expose it on "req.body".
    server.use(express.json());
    server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Accept any type, "false" would mean accept only array or string.
    
    // Create and init NestJS server based on Express instance.
    const createNestServer = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(
        AppNestModule,
        new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance)
      );
    
      app.init(); // Use when deploying to & testing with Firebase Cloud Functions.
      // await app.listen(4305); // Use when testing locally without Firebase Cloud Functions solely on NestJS.
    };
    
    createNestServer(server); // Create NestJS server.
    
    // Firebase Cloud Function for Server Side Rendering (SSR).
    exports.angularUniversalFunction = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

**app.nest.module.ts**

```js
    import { AngularUniversalModule, applyDomino } from '@nestjs/ng-universal';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    
    // Get working directory of client bundle.
    // const BROWSER_DIR = join(
    //   process.cwd(),
    //   'functions',
    //   'dist',
    //   'apps',
    //   'ditectrev-browser'
    // ); // Use when testing locally without Firebase Cloud Functions solely on NestJS.
    const BROWSER_DIR = join(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'apps', 'ditectrev-browser'); // Use when deploying to & testing with Firebase Cloud Functions.
    
    applyDomino(global, join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index.html'));
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
          bundle: require('./../functions/dist/apps/ditectrev-server/main'), // Bundle is created dynamically during build process.
          liveReload: true,
          viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR
        })
      ]
    })
    export class AppNestModule {}
```

Tested when rendering SSR solely on `NestJS` and `Firebase` Cloud Functions on `localhost` (see comments). The same behaviour. Deployed on Firebase - has the same behaviour, all other views/paths have correctly rendered SSR code in **View Page Source** when I was checking this. I did some security headers modifications and for curiosity ran tests. Not rendering the home page in **"/"** path also causes that they don't apply, otherwise it works fine! Please find 2 screenshots below. It's for the same (home) page.

[image: Correctly rendered home page with app path (and security headers works)]

[image: Home page doesn't render correctly with / path (and security headers works]

Files such as **tsconfig.json** in a folder (named **server**) where are these 2 files I'm skipping, as it should be fine, the same for **tsconfig.server.json** and **main.server.ts** in **app** folder (where browser/core code is). Wouldn't say that **app.server.module.ts** (in **app** folder) causes the problem, but this one maybe it's also worth to share. It's below:

```js
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { FlexLayoutServerModule } from '@angular/flex-layout/server';
    import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
    
    @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        FlexLayoutServerModule,
        ModuleMapLoaderModule, // For lazy loading on SSR.
        ServerModule
      ]
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
```

I also took a look into the repo https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular8-example-app
There it works fine, but the server is in Express and couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

**UPDATE**

On `localhost` when I'm rendering using only `NestJS` is works fine. But when will change on Cloud Functions for `Firebase` it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an `index.html`, which was not renamed to `index2.html` (or anything else). Only if `index.html` is renamed then Cloud Functions for Firebase renders properly the root `/` path as well.